# debugging register_activation_hook()

Tags: plugins

I'm curious if there is a known issue with WordPress or PHP where the environment may degrade to a point where WordPress simply ignores calls to register_activation_hook(). I was pulling my hair out for an hour on my local environment running MAMP when I had a coworker test the code on her machine; exact same code works on one machine but not the other.

In this case I simply wanted to append messages to the log file which I'm tailing in real-time.

```
error_log("Plugin code is being processed");

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );

function myplugin_activate()
{
    error_log("Attempting to activate");
    die("Should not activate");
}
```

The output on my machine running MAMP and clicking on the "Activate" link under my plugin:

```
[22-Sep-2011 22:37:16] Plugin code is being processed
[22-Sep-2011 22:37:16] Plugin code is being processed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little more thought, I think using a resolved path lookup might be safer:

```
function plugin_symlink_path( $file )
{
    // If the file is already in the plugin directory we can save processing time.
    if ( preg_match( '/'.preg_quote( WP_PLUGIN_DIR, '/' ).'/i', $file ) ) return $file;

    // Examine each segment of the path in reverse
    foreach ( array_reverse( explode( '/', $file ) ) as $segment )
    {
        // Rebuild the path starting from the WordPress plugin directory
        // until both resolved paths match.

        $path = rtrim($segment .'/'. $path, '/');       

        if ( __FILE__ == realpath( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $path ) )
        {
            return WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $path;
        }
    }

    // If all else fails, return the original path.
    return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I feel a bit dense for not noticing this sooner, but I finally realized that my plugins directory on my computer is a symbolic link to another location as pointed out by Kunal Bhalla in [symlinks with WP plugins](http://explog.in/blog/2011/09/15/Symlinks-wordpress/). Since `__FILE__` resolves symbolic links `register_activation_hook()` is attempting to load a file outside of the WordPress plugins path.

If you look at the `register_activation_hook()` function in plugin.php you'll see the magic seems to happen in `plugin_basename()`:

```
function register_activation_hook($file, $function) {
    $file = plugin_basename($file);
    add_action('activate_' . $file, $function);
}
```

Further examination shows that `plugin_basename()` is essentially performing pattern replacement in attempt to turn a system path into `my_plugin/my_plugin.php`; however, since `str_replace()` is using `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` as the subject, any system path outside of that the WordPress plugin directory will not produce a match to replace against:

```
function plugin_basename($file) {
    $file = str_replace('\\','/',$file); // sanitize for Win32 installs
    $file = preg_replace('|/+|','/', $file); // remove any duplicate slash
    $plugin_dir = str_replace('\\','/',WP_PLUGIN_DIR); // sanitize for Win32 installs
    $plugin_dir = preg_replace('|/+|','/', $plugin_dir); // remove any duplicate slash
    $mu_plugin_dir = str_replace('\\','/',WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR); // sanitize for Win32 installs
    $mu_plugin_dir = preg_replace('|/+|','/', $mu_plugin_dir); // remove any duplicate slash
    $file = preg_replace('#^' . preg_quote($plugin_dir, '#') . '/|^' . preg_quote($mu_plugin_dir, '#') . '/#','',$file); // get relative path from plugins dir
    $file = trim($file, '/');
    return $file;
}
```

This method seems a little short-sited, and I've found several solutions ranging from defining additional constants in `wp-config.php` to hard-coding the relative path of your plugin. Instead I think a better stop-gap method might be to use the following pattern which pre-defines the path `plugin_basename()` is attempting to extract. This can be used in place of `__FILE__` as the first parameter of `register_activation_hook()`.

```
basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/'.basename( __FILE__ );
```

This method will only work if your plugin has it's own folder in the `wp-content/plugins` directory and is called from the base plugin file. Both of these conditions seem to be generally in control of the plugin developer, though I'm curious if anyone has some opposing thoughts.

---

Additional Links:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13550
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46260

Answer (score 1):

I have used this method: insert the following code in the plugin. THen activate it.

```
function save_error()
{
   file_put_contents(ABSPATH. 'wp-content/plugins/error_activation.html', ob_get_contents());
}
add_action('activated_plugin','save_error');
```

after activation, then open yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/error_activation.html to see what errors happened.